# Do Python lists have an equivalent to dict.get?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers.  I want to know whether the number 13 appears in it and, if so, where.  Do I have to search the list twice, as in the code below?

```
if 13 in intList:
   i = intList.index(13)
```

In the case of dictionaries, there's a `get` function which will ascertain membership and perform look-up with the same search.  Is there something similar for lists?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You answered it yourself, with the `index()` method. That will throw an exception if the index is not found, so just catch that:

```
def getIndexOrMinusOne(a, x):
  try:
    return a.index(x)
  except ValueError:
    return -1
```

Comment: Never use an empty except clause. You should do except IndexError.

Comment: You're probably abusing lists if you need to do things this way; this looks like a code smell.

Comment: Uh? This works, I tested it ... The except is not empty, it contains the return?

Comment: He means you should not do a "global" except but rather specify what you are catching, ValueError, etc.

Comment: by 'empty' he means, I guess, catching all exception types, not only the one you want. This way it's easy to go over some error you weren't planing

Comment: But sometimes you can, never say never. I agree in this case naked except is not a good thing.

Comment: One code smell here is that the list should probably have been a set.

Comment: S.Lott: I guess it all depends whether the items are unique or not.

Comment: @Ali A: not at all, thanks a lot. And thanks to everyone else who commented!

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you'll just have to catch the exception...

```
try:
    i = intList.index(13)
except ValueError:
    i = some_default_value
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't a direct match for what you asked for. There was **[a discussion a while back](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-July/067263.html)** on the Python mailing list about this, and people reached the conclusion that it was probably a code smell if you needed this. Consider using a *dict* or *set* instead if you need to test membership that way.

Comment: This just condenses the syntax of the original code sample.  The performance problem is unaddressed.  Python still tests if item in list first, then searches for the index of item in the list.

Comment: @David: You're right. I should probably just delete the code and focus on the second paragraph, which was my real point. The other solutions all seem to trade the list check for an expensive exception-throw/catching situation.

Comment: Someone should re-request this in a 2016 thread on the subject :) I have a feeling that with map and reduce gaining in mainstream popularity, different opinions on what is "code smell" might surface.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the ValueError exception, or you can do:

```
i = intList.index(13) if 13 in intList else -1
```

(Python 2.5+)

BTW. if you're going to do a big batch of similar operations, you might consider building inverse dictionary value -> index.

```
intList = [13,1,2,3,13,5,13]
indexDict = defaultdict(list)
for value, index in zip(intList, range(len(intList))):
   indexDict[value].append(index)

indexDict[13]
[0, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put what you got in a function and use it:)

You can either use `if i in list: return list.index(i)` or the `try/except`, depending on your preferences.